# Overwrite existing data with data from new server in Analysis Services SSAS

Tags: ssas, connection-string, dax, ssas-tabular, dimensional-modeling

So I have a Tabular model built in SSAS which points to a specific server/Db. Basically I want to change the connection string so it points to a new datasource. Ensuring that I keep all existing table/views/calculated columns/ structures exactly the same.

Issue I'm having is that when I change the datasource (via Model -> Existing Connections), it processes the data on the new server fine, but now duplicates all the data model objects. So now there are 2 of each table/views. And no relationships exist between the new tables.

I need to basically overwrite the existing data with the data from the new server/DB? Is this achievable without it duplicating objects?

Comment: You can right click the model file and do View Code. if you're careful you should be able to re-wire the tables to use the new data source. Back up the file first... I've googled something similar recently but it referred to an older version than my 2016 project so the XML was different. I was able to do it, and it was easier than the blog post with the latest XML.

Comment: Ahh so modify the xml directly. The only question I have is, once this has been done (xml code changed), and then I re-process the cube, will this now append the new data to the old records or replace/overwrite the existing data records? I need it to do the latter.

Comment: When you re-process it'll just replace the data with the data from the new data source.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but tested this today and it has worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per TDP's comment - 'You can right-click the model file and do View Code. if you're careful you should be able to re-wire the tables to use the new data source. Back up the file first.'